# Receive the token,userid using SharedPreferences.Editor in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

Hi i have one doubt that how could i pass and receive the token using `SharedPreferences.Editor`

i have tried to pass the token by using:

```
appSharedPrefs  = this.getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);

prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

prefsEditor.putString("Userid", mUserid );
prefsEditor.putString("Token", mToken );
prefsEditor.putString("UserName", mUserName );
prefsEditor.putString("Password", mPassword );
prefsEditor.commit();
```

to pass the userid is right i think but how could i receive the username with userid in next Activity.Need Help!! Thanks

Comment: what problem u are getting in reading value from SharedPreferences in next Activity ? simply use `String str_username=appSharedPrefs.getString("UserName","defaultValue");...` for reading all values from SharedPreferences

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes..in next activity

Comment: i mean what problem u have reading values from  SharedPreferences ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i am not getting problem i need to know how to perform that

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thanks for your answer,if i pass the userid and token then can i able to get all the details of the user

Comment: You just need to use the String as @ρяσѕρєяK commented

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs  = this.getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);

String mUserid = prefs.getString("Userid", "NA");
String mToken = prefs.getString("Token", "NA" );
String mUserName = prefs.getString("UserName", "NA");
String mPassword = prefs.getString("Password", "NA");
```

NA is the default value passed to the String here, change it as you will.

Also read up http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the details in any screen if you have already saved it to `SharedPreferences`. You can git it in a below manner.

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE); // Get reference if SharedPreference
String userid = pref.getString("Userid", "no name");
String token = pref.getString("Token", "no token");
String userName = pref.getString("UserName","no username");
String mPass = pref.getString("Password","no pass");
```